# 230 V AC motor not running

Tags: motor, ac, identification, components

I have a 230 V shaded pole motor of a dehumidifier that does not work anymore. The motor makes absolutely no noise when connected to 230 V. The rotor spins smoothly, there is not much dirt in it.

That motor is very simple: 4 coils, an inner magnetic shaft, and nothing else except a component between the two coil pairs that is exactly in the middle between the two phases.

The component looks like a resistor but it is white and has golden descriptions on it like "128 UMI" and a ground symbol. And it says "N1". What kind of component is this? Could it be broken? I have measured the resistance between the phases, they are all good and the same.

Comment: If it is in contact with the coils it may be a thermal fuse.

Comment: A photo would help.

Comment: Well done folks, it was the thermal fuse. I shortened it and now its running. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description makes me think the component is probably a thermal fuse, like these from SIBBLE:

[image]
<sup>(Photo from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CBRWTZ1X))</sup>

And yes, it could be blown.